# How to comma separate the values of an multiple array object value for display

Tags: php

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [features_id] => 2
        [features_type] => TV
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [features_id] => 5
        [features_type] => New balls
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [features_id] => 6
        [features_type] => Basketball pitch
    )
)
```

For get result of my array i want to display this record separated by comma like:

> ```
>  New balls,Basketball pitch.
> ```

By using foreach how to write don't know how get this type result

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve your output without using foreach loop. Please try below code.

```
$singlArray = array_column($multiDimArray, 'features_type') // this convert multiple dimension array to single array
$finalValue= implode(',',$singlArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is fairly simple:

```
foreach($array as $item){
    echo $item->features_type.',';
}
```